# Django only get object if one of it's subobjects meets condition

Tags: python, django

So I have two models:

```py
class Business(models.Model):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Appointment(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="appointments")
```

And in my view I have the following context:

```py
def home(request):
    [...]
    context = {
        'business':Business.objects.order_by('name'),
    }
    [...]
```

Now I would get all businesses there are with their submodels "Appointment".

But what I want is only businesses where on of the existing submodels "Appointment" fullfills`author == request.author`

Also the submodels "Appointment" of a Business should only be the "Appointments" where their author equals `request.author`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do something like this:

```
business = Business.objects.filter(appointment__author=request.author)
```

Or:

```
business = Business.objects.filter(appointment__author__id=request.author.id)
```

You might want to read: [Lookups that span relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)